# Postfix local delivery only and save in a MySQL database

Tags: server, mysql, email, postfix

In my local network I have 2 PCs:

1. Ubuntu 16.04 with LAMP
2. Windows 7 with an instrument connected to this PC via special software which сontrols the device (instrument)

When the instrument ends its work, this special software can send email.

I need to send emails to Ubuntu PC and save emails in a MySQL database.  This is the only functionality that I require.

I tried to use `postfix`. I installed it `sudo apt-get install postfix` and select `local delivery only` configuration.

How can I connect postfix to MySQL? And which email do I need to use on the second PC with Windows to send emails?